# Why does my Bowyer–Watson sometimes end up with no triangles that don't share a vertex with the super triangle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, triangulation, delaunay

I have tried several different ways to caculate whether a point is within the circumcircle, but I keep getting, occassionally, no triangles that don't share a point with the original super-triangle.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

bool is_point_inside_circumcircle(const int32_t pX, const int32_t pY,
                             int32_t aX, int32_t aY, int32_t bX, int32_t bY, int32_t cX, int32_t cY)
{
    const uint32_t ab = aX * aX + aY * aY;
    const uint32_t bc = bX * bX + bY * bY;
    const uint32_t ca = cX * cX + cY * cY;

    uint32_t circumX = (ab * (cY - bY) + bc * (aY - cY) + ca * (bY - aY)) / (aX * (cY - bY) + bX * (aY - cY) + cX * (bY - aY));
    uint32_t circumY = (ab * (cX - bX) + bc * (aX - cX) + ca * (bX - aX)) / (aY * (cX - bX) + bY * (aX - cX) + cY * (bX - aX));

    circumX /= 2;
    circumY /= 2;

    uint32_t dX = aX - circumX;
    uint32_t dY = aY - circumY;
    uint32_t circumR = dX * dX + dY * dY;

    dX = pX - circumX;
    dY = pY - circumY;
    uint32_t d = dX * dX + dY * dY;

    return d <= circumR;
}

struct Edge
{
    int32_t x1;
    int32_t y1;

    int32_t x2;
    int32_t y2;
};

bool operator==(const Edge& lhs, const Edge& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.x1 == rhs.x1 && lhs.y1 == rhs.y1 && lhs.x2 == rhs.x2 && lhs.y2 == rhs.y2)
    || (lhs.x1 == rhs.x2 && lhs.y1 == rhs.y2 && lhs.x2 == rhs.x1 && lhs.y2 == rhs.y1);
}

struct Triangle
{
    Edge ab;
    Edge bc;
    Edge ca;
};

bool triangle_contains(const Triangle& tri, int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
    return (tri.ab.x1 == x && tri.ab.y1 == y) ||
    (tri.bc.x1 == x && tri.bc.y1 == y) ||
    (tri.ca.x1 == x && tri.ca.y1 == y);
}

bool operator==(const Triangle& lhs, const Triangle& rhs)
{
    return
    ((lhs.ab.x1 == rhs.ab.x1 && lhs.ab.y1 == rhs.ab.y1) ||
     (lhs.ab.x1 == rhs.bc.x1 && lhs.ab.y1 == rhs.bc.y1) ||
     (lhs.ab.x1 == rhs.ca.x1 && lhs.ca.y1 == rhs.ca.y1)) &&
     ((lhs.bc.x1 == rhs.ab.x1 && lhs.bc.y1 == rhs.ab.y1) ||
     (lhs.bc.x1 == rhs.bc.x1 && lhs.bc.y1 == rhs.bc.y1) ||
     (lhs.bc.x1 == rhs.ca.x1 && lhs.bc.y1 == rhs.ca.y1)) &&
     ((lhs.ca.x1 == rhs.ab.x1 && lhs.ca.y1 == rhs.ab.y1) ||
     (lhs.ca.x1 == rhs.bc.x1 && lhs.ca.y1 == rhs.bc.y1) ||
     (lhs.ca.x1 == rhs.ca.x1 && lhs.ca.y1 == rhs.ca.y1));
}

bool operator!=(const Triangle& lhs, const Triangle& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs==rhs);
}

std::vector<Triangle> generate_galaxy(const std::size_t numSystems)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int32_t,int32_t>> galaxy;

    std::mt19937 gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dimension(0, numSystems*3-1);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < numSystems; ++i)
    {
        galaxy.emplace_back(dimension(gen),dimension(gen));
    }

    std::vector<Triangle> triangulation;

    Triangle super;
    int32_t minX = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
    int32_t minY = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
    int32_t maxX = 0;
    int32_t maxY = 0;

    for(const std::pair<int32_t,int32_t>& n : galaxy)
    {
        if(n.first < minX) minX = n.first;
        if(n.second < minY) minY = n.second;
        if(n.first > maxX) maxX = n.first;
        if(n.second > maxY) maxY = n.second;
    }

    int32_t dX = maxX - minX;
    int32_t dY = maxY - minY;
    int32_t dM = std::max(dX,dY);
    int32_t midX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
    int32_t midY = (minY + maxY) / 2;

    super.ab.x1 = super.ca.x2 = midX - 20 * dM;
    super.ab.y1 = super.ca.y2 = midY - dM;
    super.ab.x2 = super.bc.x1 = midX;
    super.ab.y2 = super.bc.y1 = midY + 20 * dM;
    super.bc.x2 = super.ca.x1 = midX + 20 * dM;
    super.bc.y2 = super.ca.y1 = midY - dM;
    triangulation.push_back(super);

    for(const std::pair<int32_t,int32_t>& n : galaxy)
    {
        std::vector<Triangle> badTriangles;

        for(const Triangle& triangle : triangulation)
        {
            if(is_point_inside_circumcircle(n.first, n.second, triangle.ab.x1, triangle.ab.x2, triangle.bc.x1, triangle.bc.y1,
                                            triangle.ca.x1, triangle.ca.y1))
            {
                badTriangles.push_back(triangle);
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n\nAFTER NEW NODE CREATING BAD TRIANGLES" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nTriangulation (" << triangulation.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : triangulation)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nBad (" << badTriangles.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : badTriangles)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::vector<Edge> polygon;

        std::vector<Triangle>::iterator triangleItr = badTriangles.begin();
        while(triangleItr != badTriangles.end())
        {
            if(std::find_if(badTriangles.begin(),badTriangles.end(),[&](const Triangle& tri)
            {
                return
                    *triangleItr != tri && (
                    triangleItr->ab == tri.ab ||
                    triangleItr->ab == tri.bc ||
                    triangleItr->ab == tri.ca);
            }) == badTriangles.end())
            {
                polygon.push_back(triangleItr->ab);
            }
            if(std::find_if(badTriangles.begin(),badTriangles.end(),[&](const Triangle& tri)
            {
                return
                    *triangleItr != tri && (
                    triangleItr->bc == tri.ab ||
                    triangleItr->bc == tri.bc ||
                    triangleItr->bc == tri.ca);
            }) == badTriangles.end())
            {
                polygon.push_back(triangleItr->bc);
            }
            if(std::find_if(badTriangles.begin(),badTriangles.end(),[&](const Triangle& tri)
            {
                return
                    *triangleItr != tri && (
                    triangleItr->ca == tri.ab ||
                    triangleItr->ca == tri.bc ||
                    triangleItr->ca == tri.ca);
            }) == badTriangles.end())
            {
                polygon.push_back(triangleItr->ca);
            }

            ++triangleItr;
        }
        triangulation.erase(std::remove_if(triangulation.begin(),triangulation.end(),[&](const Triangle& tri)
        {
            for(const Triangle& triangle : badTriangles)
            {
                if(tri == triangle)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }),triangulation.end());

        std::cout << "\n\nAFTER ADDING EDGES TO POLYGON BECAUSE NOT SHARED IN BAD TRIANGLES AND REMOVE BAD TRIANGLES FROM TRIANGULATION" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nTriangulation (" << triangulation.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : triangulation)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nBad (" << badTriangles.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : badTriangles)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nPoly (" << polygon.size() << ")";
        for(const Edge& e : polygon)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << e.x1 << "," << e.y1 << " > " << e.x2 << "," << e.y2;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for(const Edge& edge : polygon)
        {
            Triangle newTri;
            newTri.ab = edge;
            Edge bc;
            bc.x1 = edge.x2;
            bc.y1 = edge.y2;
            bc.x2 = n.first;
            bc.y2 = n.second;
            Edge ca;
            ca.x1 = n.first;
            ca.y1 = n.second;
            ca.x2 = edge.x1;
            ca.y2 = edge.y1;
            newTri.bc = bc;
            newTri.ca = ca;
            triangulation.push_back(newTri);
        }

        std::cout << "\n\nADDING NEW TRIANGLES FROM EDGES TO TRIANGULATION" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nTriangulation (" << triangulation.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : triangulation)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nBad (" << badTriangles.size() << ")";
        for(const Triangle& tri : badTriangles)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  "
            << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  "
            << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "NODE X,Y: " << n.first << "," << n.second
        << "\nPoly (" << polygon.size() << ")";
        for(const Edge& e : polygon)
            std::cout << "\n\t" << e.x1 << "," << e.y1 << " > " << e.x2 << "," << e.y2;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    triangulation.erase(std::remove_if(triangulation.begin(),triangulation.end(),[&](const Triangle& tri)
    {
        return triangle_contains(tri,super.ab.x1,super.ab.y1) ||
            triangle_contains(tri,super.bc.x1,super.bc.y1) ||
            triangle_contains(tri,super.ca.x1,super.ca.y1);
    }),triangulation.end());

    // every edge in triangulation is now the connection of vertices

    return triangulation;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Triangle> galaxy = generate_galaxy(4);

    std::cout << "\n\nOUTCOMES:\n" << std::endl;
    for(const Triangle& tri : galaxy)
    {
        std::cout << tri.ab.x1 << "," << tri.ab.y1 << "  >  " << tri.ab.x2 << "," << tri.ab.y2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << tri.bc.x1 << "," << tri.bc.y1 << "  >  " << tri.bc.x2 << "," << tri.bc.y2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << tri.ca.x1 << "," << tri.ca.y1 << "  >  " << tri.ca.x2 << "," << tri.ca.y2 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried taking some of the methods from https://github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/delaunay-triangulation/blob/master/dt/delaunay.cpp as well in the hope that it would help but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

The output from the above looks like this when there's no resulting triangles:

```
--------------------------------------------


AFTER NEW NODE CREATING BAD TRIANGLES
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Triangulation (1)
        -154,-1  6,167  166,-1
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Bad (1)
        -154,-1  6,167  166,-1


AFTER ADDING EDGES TO POLYGON BECAUSE NOT SHARED IN BAD TRIANGLES AND REMOVE BAD TRIANGLES FROM TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Triangulation (0)
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Bad (1)
        -154,-1  6,167  166,-1
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Poly (3)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > -154,-1


ADDING NEW TRIANGLES FROM EDGES TO TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Triangulation (3)
        -154,-1  6,167  2,10
        6,167  166,-1  2,10
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Bad (1)
        -154,-1  6,167  166,-1
NODE X,Y: 2,10
Poly (3)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > -154,-1

--------------------------------------------


AFTER NEW NODE CREATING BAD TRIANGLES
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Triangulation (3)
        -154,-1  6,167  2,10
        6,167  166,-1  2,10
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Bad (2)
        -154,-1  6,167  2,10
        6,167  166,-1  2,10


AFTER ADDING EDGES TO POLYGON BECAUSE NOT SHARED IN BAD TRIANGLES AND REMOVE BAD TRIANGLES FROM TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Triangulation (1)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Bad (2)
        -154,-1  6,167  2,10
        6,167  166,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10


ADDING NEW TRIANGLES FROM EDGES TO TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Triangulation (5)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
        -154,-1  6,167  3,6
        2,10  -154,-1  3,6
        6,167  166,-1  3,6
        166,-1  2,10  3,6
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Bad (2)
        -154,-1  6,167  2,10
        6,167  166,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 3,6
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10

--------------------------------------------


AFTER NEW NODE CREATING BAD TRIANGLES
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Triangulation (5)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
        -154,-1  6,167  3,6
        2,10  -154,-1  3,6
        6,167  166,-1  3,6
        166,-1  2,10  3,6
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  3,6
        2,10  -154,-1  3,6
        6,167  166,-1  3,6
        166,-1  2,10  3,6


AFTER ADDING EDGES TO POLYGON BECAUSE NOT SHARED IN BAD TRIANGLES AND REMOVE BAD TRIANGLES FROM TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Triangulation (1)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  3,6
        2,10  -154,-1  3,6
        6,167  166,-1  3,6
        166,-1  2,10  3,6
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10


ADDING NEW TRIANGLES FROM EDGES TO TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Triangulation (5)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
        -154,-1  6,167  4,5
        2,10  -154,-1  4,5
        6,167  166,-1  4,5
        166,-1  2,10  4,5
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  3,6
        2,10  -154,-1  3,6
        6,167  166,-1  3,6
        166,-1  2,10  3,6
NODE X,Y: 4,5
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10

--------------------------------------------


AFTER NEW NODE CREATING BAD TRIANGLES
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Triangulation (5)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
        -154,-1  6,167  4,5
        2,10  -154,-1  4,5
        6,167  166,-1  4,5
        166,-1  2,10  4,5
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  4,5
        2,10  -154,-1  4,5
        6,167  166,-1  4,5
        166,-1  2,10  4,5


AFTER ADDING EDGES TO POLYGON BECAUSE NOT SHARED IN BAD TRIANGLES AND REMOVE BAD TRIANGLES FROM TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Triangulation (1)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  4,5
        2,10  -154,-1  4,5
        6,167  166,-1  4,5
        166,-1  2,10  4,5
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10


ADDING NEW TRIANGLES FROM EDGES TO TRIANGULATION
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Triangulation (5)
        166,-1  -154,-1  2,10
        -154,-1  6,167  10,8
        2,10  -154,-1  10,8
        6,167  166,-1  10,8
        166,-1  2,10  10,8
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Bad (4)
        -154,-1  6,167  4,5
        2,10  -154,-1  4,5
        6,167  166,-1  4,5
        166,-1  2,10  4,5
NODE X,Y: 10,8
Poly (4)
        -154,-1 > 6,167
        2,10 > -154,-1
        6,167 > 166,-1
        166,-1 > 2,10


OUTCOMES:


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.620 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I can see that the triangulation only contains triangles that share a vertex with the original super-triangle that was calculated. So I know why they're all removed, but I can't find any information online as to why this would happen. I step through the process and match it up to the description and images on [Bowyer–Watson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) and I can't see any issues.

Comment: Why are you using integers for everything?

Comment: @samgak I don't think it really matters or is relevant to the question.

Comment: It might have an effect because of rounding errors introduced when doing integer division. I was just curious because the source code you linked uses doubles.

Comment: I'm using ints because other source code I was using previously used ints. Again, I doubt it's going to have much of an affect, but if you think otherwise please post an answer with your solution.

Comment: I'm  not going to debug your code; that's your job. Draw the points, execute the code step by step, and watch the results at each step compared with what you expected. But I'll give you a pair of advises: 1) Don't use `int`. You may suffer overflow and/or truncating nasty effects. 2) Even with `double` it's not enoug [read why](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/classroomExamplesNonrobustness.pdf) 3) Use [Robust Predicates](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html) to solve 2).

Comment: So I solved my problem. But what do you mean "I'm not going to debug your code" what is the purpose of this website if not to get help debugging code?